# Zooming in a specific div in Cordova/Ionic

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I added the viewport with properties allowing zooming/scaling. And I added these to the native code:

```
WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

I am able to zoom, but along with my view, `ion-header-bar` and `ion-nav-bar` gets zoomed. I tried giving the header css, to keep it fixed:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

but still, it'd get zoomed.

My **index.html** has an `ion-header-bar`, which contains an image.
The templates go into

```
<ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>
```

The template in which I require zooming in a particular div is having a 'ion-view` and it looks like:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            icon1
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            icon2
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <div>
        Multiple divs in here, which are containers for html and css data we receive via AJAX requests. And this is here I need zooming in.
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

PS: Would it matter if I add a full HTML code(with meta viewport, no header, but body and divs) inside the `ion-view`?

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to get similar functionality and was able to get it to work using [ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/).

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; ">
  <div></div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: My divs are modified via DOM after AJAX requests. I tried adding these divs within the `ion-scroll` but then the received data won't load, i.e the div within ion-scroll remains blank. I tried adding the ion-scroll code within the jQuery where I am modifying the HTML of the div like this: `$("#container").html('<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%; "><div>' + data + '</div></ion-scroll>');` and the doc loads, but then I can't scroll.
Just to be sure I added a div with some text in the HTML, within ion-scroll and I was able to zoom in that text.

Comment: In 1.2+, you have to add this as well:

`.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);
})`
Via https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-latest-version-1-7-14-pinch-zoom-is-not-working/42832

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @laughinpine above, I came up with this solution in Ionic 4:

```
<ion-content scrollX scrollY>
  <div #map style="background-image: url('/assets/images/map.png');">
  </div>
</ion-content>


import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MapPage
  @ViewChild('map') public map: ElementRef;

  private readonly minZoom: number = 0.3;
  private readonly maxZoom: number = 2.0;
  private readonly zoomVelocity: number = 0.005;

  public constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  private addPinchToMap(): void {
    const hammerTime = new Hammer.Manager(this.map.nativeElement, { touchAction: 'pan-x pan-y' });
    const pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
    let lastZoom: number = 1; // Default original zoom

    hammerTime.add(pinch);

    hammerTime.on('pinchin', (event: MSGestureEvent) => {
      let newZoom = lastZoom - this.zoomVelocity;
      newZoom = newZoom < this.minZoom ? this.minZoom : newZoom;
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.map.nativeElement, 'zoom', newZoom);
      lastZoom = newZoom;
    });

    hammerTime.on('pinchout', (event: MSGestureEvent) => {
      let newZoom = lastZoom + this.zoomVelocity;
      newZoom = newZoom > this.maxZoom ? this.maxZoom : newZoom;
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.map.nativeElement, 'zoom', newZoom);
      lastZoom = newZoom;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I confirm this solution works, only differences, I had to wrap the #map in a #mapContainer, add style to w,h: 100%, overflow: auto, position: relative; and for #map position: relative, height: 900px, width: 900px; in scss.

Comment: @JackiedegliInnocenti how you get it works? can please share an example code with me?

Comment: @Shanu Is there something about the above code example that is not working for you?

Comment: @Russ Yes above code is not working for me. Is there any sample project that i can refer? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Shanu For the html, css and js code that would be more helpful you could open a new question as here the OP one has already been answered by this answer author and so the community.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to use [hammerjs](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for multi-touch gestures and map pinch out and pinch in to zoom the content using css.

Something like this:

```
var hammerTime = new Hammer.Manager($('div.youWantToScale')[0], {touchAction: "pan-x pan-y"});
var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
var lastZoom;
hammerTime.add(pinch);
hammerTime.on("pinchout pinchin", function(e) {
   var currentZoom = Number($('div.youWantToScale').css("zoom"));
   if (lastZoom) {
      var newZoom = currentZoom + (e.scale - lastZoom);

      //bounds checking for your zoom, min=1 and max=3 here
      newZoom = newZoom < 1 ? 1 : (newZoom > 3 ? 3 : newZoom); 
      $('div.youWantToScale').css("zoom", newZoom);
   } 
   lastZoom = e.scale;
});

hammerTime.on("pinchstart", function (e) {
   //Seems clunky, but reset the lastZoom on a new pinch   
   lastZoom = undefined;
});
```

Comment: I am able to zoom in the div I want to, but now I can't scroll down. And now the app is facing heavy lag on that page, due to the plugin.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps try adding `var pan = new Hammer.Pan()` and adjusting the `hammerTime.add` to `hammerTime.add(pinch, pan)`  Seems like hammer might be overridding the normal touch events...  Hmm, also, does adding the css: `overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` help at all?

Comment: Thanks for replying again, but no change at all. Still unable to scroll. And the _heavy lag_ is still the same